# Different forms of the plane

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given $V=span ((-5,4,4), (-5,7,5))$ how to show that equation of V is $-8x+5y-15z=2$

I was trying to do the rref form but still it does not give me any hints about that.

How to show that?

Comment: Is there no more information to go along with the question?

Comment: Part of a broader thing but i think there are no more relevant info

Comment: There must be something?

Comment: The *span* is a vector space, so it **must** contain the origin. It cannot be a plane that not pass thorough $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: You are right origin is (6,1,-3)